# How to fix duplicate key error while SET in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-update

I was doing the following operation on a table:

```
UPDATE tname
SET cname = cname + INTERVAL 8 HOUR;
```

In the table, the cname column is for timestamps and set as a primary key. The operation is to add 8 hours to all the values of cname column.

But the operation gets an error message because of a duplicate key. I don't know how this could happen exactly but what I guess is that there was column 'cname' which has the values with 8 hours interval.
So when it tries to add 8 hours and write it, it gets the duplicate key error.

I have two questions:

1. If the operation gets the error, is the table inconsistent? I mean some rows are added with 8 hours and some rows are not?
2. How can I complete this operation without duplicate key error?

Comment: if cname is primary, it has an implicit unique index, hence if there exists another record with cname + 8 hours, you get this error. I would say that it is bad table design to change the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update itself is creating the duplicate; depending on the order in which rows are processed, you might end up with a new value that conflicts with an existing one.

A common workaround is to use `order by`:

```
UPDATE tname
SET cname = cname + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
ORDER BY cname desc;
```

The query starts by updating the greatest date, then processes the rows in descending order, which prevents conflicts from happening.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, unless you execute the query in a transaction, and use `ROLLBACK;` if there's an error.
2. You can check first whether there are any duplicates:

```
UPDATE tname AS t
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM tname AS t1
    JOIN tname AS t2 ON t1.cname = t2.cname + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) as dups
SET t.cname = t.cname + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
WHERE dups.count = 0
```